# Rotate the camera with glm and glfw

Tags: c++, camera, glfw, glm-math

I have the following code:

```
void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
    {
        if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
               const float radius = std::sqrt(std::pow(camX, 2) + 
               std::pow(camY, 2) + std::pow(camZ, 2));
                camX = (cos(ypos) + sin(ypos)) * radius;
                camY = (sin(xpos) + cos(ypos)) * radius;
                camZ = (cos(ypos) + sin(xpos)) * radius;
       }
}
```

this code is naturally rotate my camera but I can't get what I'm looking for. So let me describe what I want to do:

if I move my mouse, I want to rotate the camera, the radius is the distance between my camera and my model (the model is naturally at (0, 0, 0)).

```
view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(camX, camY, camZ),
                        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f) + cameraFront,
                        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

the `cameraFront` is for translation and it works.

Could someone help me?

thanks